# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:8080/api/controller/method' from origin 'http://localhost:4100' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-3.0

Iam using backend as asp.net core 3.0 and front end angular7 while login to the application it throwing an cors orgin policy error how to resolve it , i tried lot of google but its not working any kind.

here is the below error its throwing 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:8080/api/controller/method' from origin 'http://localhost:4100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

any help...please thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be the same problem as this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074290/angular-6-asp-net-not-core-web-api-cors-request-fails

Comment: I am using appsetting.json not web.config..but even I have implemented those three steps which is mentioned in your comment link...but its not working....

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your Startup.cs ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `CORS` for you asp.net core 3.0 prject in startup.cs, refer to the below link which uses cors policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Or you could directly add `app.UseCors` in `Configure` in startup with correct order, for example:

```
app.UseRouting();
// place the call to UseCors before any other middleware that use CORS 
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4100")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: thanks it works but..small change i just added AllowAnyOrigin and removed AllowCredentials

and added this two lines in ConfiureServices method
 services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

from the below references 
https://forums.asp.net/t/2156837.aspx?Why+asp+net+core+threws+Endpoint+Routing+error+

Comment: @sakinala great, that is applied to your condition.Could you accept the answer if you have resolved it?